# ¿Cómo hago para retornar el registro cuando se almacena en la base de datos?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Estoy creando una web api con .net 6; no sé como retornar el registro almacenado actualmente en la base de datos con con un mensaje personalizado

Este es mi condigo:

```csharp
namespace API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/asset/")]
    public class AssetController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;
        private readonly IMapper mapper;
        public AssetController(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext, IMapper map)
        {
            db = applicationDbContext;
            mapper = map;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("create/")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([FromBody] Asset asset)
        {
            db.Add(asset);
            var x = await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok("Registro exitoso!");
        }
    }
}
```

Quisiera retornar a mi fronted algo como esto:

```json
[{
    "context"{
        "Message":"Registro exitoso!"
        "result":x,
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return Ok(new { Message = "Registro exitoso", Result = true });

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y como devuelves el registro que acabas de almacenar en la bd ? en esta caso es `x`

Comment: Estas recibiendo un Clase 'Asset', puedes imprimir alguna propiedad de esta clase en el resultado. Ejemplo:  
      

            return Ok(new { Message = "Registro exitoso", Result = asset.Name });